# Which headers should I add to a CURL request to access WSDL

Tags: php, curl, soap

I'm trying to implement a SOAP webservice client to get the state of a package.
I'm sending this request throuth SOAP UI and the server is returning the response properly

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:tem="http://tempuri.org/">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetEnvios>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:login>USER</tem:login>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:pass>PASSWORD</tem:pass>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:codigoIdioma>3082</tem:codigoIdioma>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:tipoFiltro>0</tem:tipoFiltro>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:valorFiltroDesde>038224807003</tem:valorFiltroDesde>
        
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:fechaDesde>01/01/2021</tem:fechaDesde>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:fechaHasta>31/12/2021</tem:fechaHasta>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:tipoInformacion>1</tem:tipoInformacion>
      </tem:GetEnvios>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

But when I try to check the webservice through my service client using CURL i always get the same answer

```
<sEnvelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"><sBody><sFault><faultcode xmlns:a="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/05/addressing/none">a:ActionNotSupported</faultcode><faultstring xml:lang="es-ES">The message with Action '' cannot be processed at the receiver, due to a ContractFilter mismatch at the EndpointDispatcher. This may be because of either a contract mismatch (mismatched Actions between sender and receiver) or a binding/security mismatch between the sender and the receiver.  Check that sender and receiver have the same contract and the same binding (including security requirements, e.g. Message, Transport, None).</faultstring></sFault></sBody></sEnvelope>
```

My connection class does

```
$datos = "<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\" xmlns:tem=\"http://tempuri.org/\">
   <soapenv:Header/>
   <soapenv:Body>
      <tem:GetEnvios>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:login>user</tem:login>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:pass>password</tem:pass>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:codigoIdioma>3082</tem:codigoIdioma>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:tipoFiltro>0</tem:tipoFiltro>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:valorFiltroDesde>038224807003</tem:valorFiltroDesde>

         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:fechaDesde>01/01/2021</tem:fechaDesde>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:fechaHasta>31/12/2021</tem:fechaHasta>
         <!--Optional:-->
         <tem:tipoInformacion>1</tem:tipoInformacion>
      </tem:GetEnvios>
   </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>";

        $headers = array(
            "Content-type: text/xml;charset=\"utf-8\""); //SOAPAction: your op URL

        // PHP cURL  for https connection with auth
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 10);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $datos); // the SOAP request
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);

        // converting
        $response = curl_exec($ch);
```

I guess that it could by something related to header but I don't know which ones should be.

Thank you

Comment: Is there any reason why you aren't using PHP's SOAP client? It's likely to make things simpler, I would expect. https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.soap.php

Comment: This is because there's a library doing some post requests again this webservice and i wanted to extend the functionality adding a get request

Comment: Maybe you should check how the library is doing it, then

Comment: But the library is only doing POST requests, and I have to implement the first GET function.

Comment: Are you _sure_ it's a GET request you need? Because SOAP doesn't usually use GETs, and GET requests don't have a request body containing XML